# Cipher decryption / encryption changing results

Tags: java, encryption, rsa, badpaddingexception

I'm reverse engineering some code which is decrypting data, hoping I'll be able to encrypt it back and obtain the same data it started with, for [reasons that would make this question too long and off-topic](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/19803/reversing-a-java-digest-function-with-known-public-key-and-source-code).

```
public void Test() throws Exception {

    String pk_enc = //...

    String hashStr_64 = //...

    byte[] hashStr_encrypted = Base64.decode(hashStr_64);

    X509EncodedKeySpec e = new X509EncodedKeySpec(Base64.decode(pk_enc));
    KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
    RSAPublicKey RSApublicKey = (RSAPublicKey) keyFactory.generatePublic(e);
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1PADDING");
    cipher.init(2, RSApublicKey); // '2' means decrypt
    byte[] hashStr_decrypted = cipher.doFinal(hashStr_encrypted);
    String hashStr_result = new String(hashStr_decrypted);

    // Now in reverse...
    Cipher cipher1 = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1PADDING");
    // instantiating a new cipher or using the original one makes no difference
    cipher1.init(1, RSApublicKey); // '1' means encrypt
    byte[] hashStr_encrypted_reverse = cipher1.doFinal(hashStr_decrypted);
    String hashStr_64_reverse = Base64.encode(hashStr_encrypted_reverse);
}
```

All the code before `// Now in reverse...` cannot be changed, but that doesn't mean it's impossible to convert `hashStr_result` back to `hashStr_64`, right?

However, the code I've wrote after, that should do just that, doesn't work.
`hashStr_encrypted_reverse` is different from `hashStr_encrypted`. Why is that and how can I fix it?

Another sign that something went wrong in the encryption is what happens if I try to decrypt again...

```
// Decrypt again
Cipher cipher2 = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1PADDING");
cipher2.init(2, RSApublicKey);
byte[] hashStr_decrypted_again = cipher.doFinal(hashStr_encrypted_reverse);
```

This throws:

> javax.crypto.BadPaddingException

I don't really care, but maybe it could help answer the question.

Comment: That's not how RSA works. One operation uses the public key, the other operation uses the private key. You can't do both operations with the public key.

Comment: That's something I thought about, but you'll see that we have a *public* key actually *decrypting* data. My limited understanding is that with an RSA public key one can only encrypt, not decrypt. So I thought this works differently from the RSA I know (or that surely it would be possible to encrypt it back). Thanks for the tip: I'll research more in this direction!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Terminology will be confusing. There are 4 RSA operations, best described as: signing, verifying, encrypting, decrypting. Mapping these to a lower-level and using only the language of encryption and decryption, these map as follows:

**sign-verify pair**

- signing -> encrypt with private key
- verifying -> decrypt with public key

**encrypt-decrypt pair**

- encrypting -> encrypt with public key
- decrypting -> decrypt with private key.

As you can see, each pair of operations has the private key on one side and the public key on the other.

Answer (score 2):

As @JamesKPolk said in his comment, this isn't how RSA works. RSA is an *asymmetric* encryption algorithm: there are two keys, public and private. A symmetric algorithm (e.g., AES) has a single key, which is used for both encryption and decryption, and that key must be kept safe, except to the sending and receiving parties.

Why asymmetric encryption?

- You can encrypt with a public key (typically someone else's key that they've shared with you), and they must use their private key to decrypt it. Anyone can have the public key (that's why it's **public**), but it cannot be used to read the encrypted message. This is where you are having your problem.
- Also, you can encrypt a message with a private key (typically your own), and anyone else can use your public key to decrypt it. This is how digital signatures are implemented: for example, you would encrypt a digest of a document, and anyone can verify your signature if they have your public key, but no one else could have signed it.